# Linux printf command not printing leading 0

Tags: awk

```
printf("TRL1%13s%013s%07s%07s%80s99%74s", nTotDBAmt, nTotCRAmt, nTotDBCnt, nTotCRCnt,"", "") >> sDAT_FILE
```

We are migrating from Unix to Linux.
This command works fine for unix, but in Linux.
It prints

```
TRL1     46038002   1270804215   1857   1843                                                                                99
```

It prints a blank instead of zero.

Comment: I removed the `printf` tag because it appears you're using the awk function. If I'm wrong, please elaborate! I also formatted the code and output using the `{}` formatting tool, in order to make it easier to distinguish.

Comment: Care to include the line that is printed in Unix to examine the differences?

Answer (score 0):

Linux usually has *GNU awk* installed. I don't know which version of *awk* supports leading zeroes for the %s format string, but it seems to be non-standard.

Try %013d instead of %013s.

Comment: perl's printf does. eg. `perl -e 'printf("FOO%013s\n", 2)'`. And this probably also applies to scripts converted with `a2p` -- though I can't check that, since they removed the `a2p`, `s2p`, `find2perl` utilities since perl 5.22.0.

Comment: Also it's quite a stretch to say that GNU awk is the default on "Linux". On most debian-derived distros, awk is mawk, not gawk.

Comment: Any awk I've inspected uses the native/libc `sprintf()` in their `printf()` implementation, the observed behaviour is [BSD-ish](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?printf%283%29) where a 0 flag is valid for all conversions (excepting `%n`), unlike POSIX which [defines it for numeric conversions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) only. This happens on Solaris even with `gawk`.

Comment: This is interesting information.

Answer (score 0):

From the question it is not very clear what exactly you want to achieve

If you are trying to print decimal numbers, I would write

```
printf("%013d",a);
```

`0` - It Left-pads the number with zeroes instead of spaces

If you are trying to print characters, I would write

```
printf("%*s",13,"string which needs to be printed")
```

Here we are specifying the length of chars to be printed as an integer argument to printf(), `*` gets substituted as passed argument